# my query.findInBackground not getting executed in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse for my data in android app. for some reason the code inside query.findInBackground is not getting executed.

```
public List<Date> sessionHeaderFetch(){
        Log.d("test", "session fetch entry");
        ParseQuery<Sessions> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class);
        final List<Date> sessionHeaders = null;
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Sessions>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Sessions> sessionsObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                Log.d("test", "session internal entry");
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("test", "Retrieved " + sessionsObjects.size() + " sessions");
                    for (Sessions session : sessionsObjects) {
                        sessionHeaders.add(session.getNetsDate());
                    };
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d("test", "session last value");
        return sessionHeaders;
    }
```

the code inside public void done() is not all invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it by using an ArrayList, there were some problems with the List initialization and also the results are fetched asynchronous manner so my functions which calls these functions were getting null values so I had to write by calling functions that calls the parse fetch functions asynchronously as well.

but the query can be written like this and it works.

```
 public void sessionFetch(Date headers, final ParseIOListener<Sessions> listener){
        ParseQuery<Sessions> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class);
        Log.d("test", "input header" + headers );
        query.whereEqualTo("NetsDate",headers);
        final ArrayList<Sessions> sessionsData = new ArrayList<Sessions>();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Sessions>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Sessions> sessionsObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (Sessions session : sessionsObjects) {
                        Log.d("test", "output objects" + session.toString() );
                        sessionsData.add(session);
                        Log.d("test", "Retrieved -- sessions" + sessionsObjects.size() );
                    }

                    listener.onDataRetrieved(sessionsData);
                } else {
                    listener.onDataRetrieveFail(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

If you want more details on implementing this, [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757494/parsequeryadapter-not-fetching-the-items/27757960#27757960)

Comment: what is "Session" in using parsequery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have understood how to query correctly in Parse.

When you define the parse query. The get query should contain the name of the table that you are trying to query. Also the queries returned will be ParseObjects normally, so I would expect that your callback should be new FindCallback().

I've adjusted the parse query below.

```
    ParseQuery<Sessions> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseTableName");
    final List<Date> sessionHeaders = null;
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> sessionsObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            Log.d("test", "session internal entry");
            if (e == null) {
                // Find succeeded, so do something
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Obviously you will need to replace "ParseTableName" with the name of the table that you are trying to query in parse.

Comment: it doesn't have to be like that, we can use ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class); and the Sessions is a model class for Parse Object which will extend ParseObject. thanks for your answer anyways @Jaydev

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you feel the code is not being invoked is because you are returning from the method before the ".findInBackground" operation has completed. Remember the query is performed on a background thread. So this is how your code will run:

1. **ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class);**
2. **final List sessionHeaders = null;**
   ------> 1. **query.findInBackground** (Popped onto background thread)
3. **return sessionHeaders;** (by the time you get here, sessionHeaders will probably still be null).

So change the logic of the code and wait till the callback returns before doing any processing on the "sessionHeaders" object.