# ParseQueryAdapter not fetching the items

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a ListView and I am using Parse.com for data, I am using a ParseQueryAdapter to pump the ListView. But I don't see the data being fetched by the adapter.

here is my code..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ArrayList<Date> dateHeaders;
    private HashMap<Date,ArrayList<Sessions>> dateContent;

    private ParseQueryAdapter<Sessions> sessionsQueryAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("test", "query");
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Sessions.class);

        //sessionHeaderFetch();
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Sessions>  factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Sessions>(){
            @Override
            public ParseQuery<Sessions> create() {
                ParseQuery<Sessions> query = Sessions.getQuery();
                query.include("sessionId");
                query.include("Location");
                Log.d("test", "query");
                return query;
            }
        };

        sessionsQueryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Sessions>(this, factory){
            public View getItemView(Sessions sessions, View view, ViewGroup parent){
                if(view == null){
                    view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.session_list_item, null);
                }
                Log.d("test", "adapter");
                TextView teamName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.teamName);
                TextView location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location);
                TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.netsTime);
                TextView slots = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slots);
                TextView bookedSlots = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.players);
                TextView openSlots = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.openSlots);
                teamName.setText(sessions.getSessionId());
                location.setText(sessions.getLocation());
                time.setText((CharSequence) sessions.getNetsDate());
                slots.setText(sessions.getSlots());
                bookedSlots.setText(sessions.getOpenSlots());
                openSlots.setText(sessions.getOpenSlots());
                return view;
            }
        };

        sessionsQueryAdapter.setAutoload(false);
        sessionsQueryAdapter.setPaginationEnabled(false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        sessionsQueryAdapter.setTextKey("sessionId");
        listView.setAdapter(sessionsQueryAdapter);

    }
}
```

along with other getter and setters I have the following method as well inside my Parse Model class.

```
public static ParseQuery<Sessions> getQuery() {
        Log.d("test", "inside query");
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class);
    }
```

Parse class

```
@ParseClassName("Sessions")
public class Sessions extends ParseObject {
    public Sessions(){

    }

    public String sessionId;
    public String location;
    public String netNo;
    public String userId;
    public int slots;
    public int openSlots;
    public Date netsDate;

    public String getSessionId() {
        return getString("SessionId");
    }

    public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        put("SessionId", sessionId);
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return getString("Location");
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        put("Location", location);
    }

    public String getNetNo() {
        return getString("NetNo");
    }

    public void setNetNo(String netNo) {
        put("NetNo", netNo);
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return getString("UserId");
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        put("UserId", userId);
    }

    public int getSlots() {
        return getInt("Slots");
    }

    public void setSlots(int slots) {
        put("Slots", slots);
    }

    public int getOpenSlots() {
        return getInt("OpenSlots");
    }

    public void setOpenSlots(int openSlots) {
        put("OpenSlots", openSlots);
    }

    public Date getNetsDate() {
        return getDate("NetsDate");
    }

    public void setNetsDate(Date netsDate) {
        put("NetsDate", netsDate);
    }

    public static ParseQuery<Sessions> getQuery() {
        Log.d("test", "inside query");
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see it get logged out? eg "inside query" and "query"?

Comment: nothing is getting logged..only the Log.d("test", "query"); below setContentView is getting executed.. not sure why

Comment: So do you have a Session class and is it annotated with @ParseClass?

Comment: Just to verify, your table name on the Parse dashboard is "Sessions"? First thing I would try, is removing you `.include()` from your query. Those are for including sub classes. But your id is only a string. Have you been able to retrieve any data in another query?

Comment: yes its is there in my dashboard, "Sessions" tried without .include() as well and also with and without .whereEqualsTo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68140/discussion-between-binghammer-and-bala-sivagnanam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you shared your code with me in the chat, I believe this is the best solution for you: 
Change your parseIO to this:

```
public class ParseIO {  

public void sessionFetch(Date headers, final ParseIOListener<Sessions> listener){ 
     ParseQuery<Sessions> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class); 
     query.whereEqualTo("NetsDate",headers); 
     final ArrayList<Sessions> sessionsData = new ArrayList<Sessions>(); 
     query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Sessions>() { 
       @Override 
       public void done(List<Sessions> sessionsObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) { 
            if (e == null) { 
               for (Sessions session : sessionsObjects) { 
                  sessionsData.add(session); 
               } 
               listener.onDataRetrieved(sessionsData); 
            } else { 
                listener.onDataRetrieveFail(e); 
            } 
         } 
     });  
 } 

 public void sessionHeaderFetch(final ParseIOListener<Date> listener){ 

      Log.d("test", "session fetch entry"); 
      ParseQuery<Sessions> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Sessions.class); 
      final ArrayList<Date> sessionHeaders = new ArrayList<Date>(); 
      query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Sessions>() { 
           @Override 
           public void done(List<Sessions> sessionsObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) { 
                if (e == null) { 
                    Log.d("test", "Retrieved -- hello" + sessionsObjects.size() + " sessions"); 
                    for (Sessions session : sessionsObjects) { 
                        sessionHeaders.add(session.getNetsDate()); 
                    } 
                    Log.d("test", "Parse fetched headers" + sessionHeaders.size()); 
                    listener.onDataRetrieved(sessionHeaders); 
                } else { 
                   Log.d("test", "Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
                   listener.onDataRetrieveFail(e); 
                } 
            } 
       }); 

  } 

  public interface ParseIOListener<T>{ 
       void onDataRetrieved(ArrayList<T> listOfData); 
       void onDataRetrieveFail(ParseException e); 
  } 
}
```

Now, if you notice your method returns void. But requires an interface. So when you call this method you can set up the interface, and when it is called it will contain your data
so for example to get headers:

```
 sessionHeaderFetch(new ParseIOListener<Date>() { 
     @Override 
     public void onDataRetrieved(ArrayList<Date> listOfData) { 
         //here you have your listOfData
     } 

     @Override 
     public void onDataRetrieveFail(ParseException e) { 
         //error. Log it out and handle it here
     } 
 });
```